# Visual Studio ASP.NET Template Incomplete (MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I got really weird problem. I am starting to learn MVC but my ASP.NET template seems to be incomplete and does not support MVC at all. It doesn't matter which version of .NET Framework I choose. Look:

[image]

[image]

What is more weird, my ASP.NET MVC 4 Template from previous version of visual studio works fine, without any issues (I can add views, controllers etc). BUT ONLY if I choose .NET Framework lower than 4.5.2.

[image]

[image]

What I already did:

- I tried command: devenv /installvstemplates
- I did repair installation of visual studio and its updates
- I uninstalled all addons and extensions

What I do not want to do:

- I dont want to clean reinstall Visual Studio

What I think I can do to fix this:

- copy cache from someone and paste it to my \Common7\IDE, but I do not
  have access to working cache files.

I would really appreciate your help guys.

**/edit** (I am sorry for my mistake with adding answer)

So I tried to fix it as i didn't receive any answer, I tried many things from google results, many pointing to this site but nothing worked.

I uninstalled visual studio, cleaned registry, used /uninstall /force with 2012, 2013 and all updates isos with no luck.

I tried this solution: 
[Can't create new MVC5 project or any other ASP .NET projects in Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25270008/cant-create-new-mvc5-project-or-any-other-asp-net-projects-in-visual-studio-20)
but it didn't work either.

Does anyone has any idea? I will give you some reward if your answer help me.

I would really appreciate anything. Point me to some direction.

- **ONLY MVC 5 doesn't work, no templates are shown (in one asp.net

  template) and if I download mvc 5 template from the web, or convert
  my existing mvc 4 project to mvc 5 it stops showing "add controller,
  add view options"**

All MVC 4 projects and templates are working without any issues at all.

**/edit 2**

**=== WORKAROUND ===**

If someone tries to resolve this issue, basically I coudn't do it, but I found workaround which is ugly and simple:

1. Deleted every single extension AND every VS Update
2. Uninstalled Visual Studio
3. Uninstalled it again using /force method
4. Cleared its every trace and the registry traces I was able to found
5. Used TuneUp utilities to clear broken registry keys
6. Uninstalled SQL Server 2014
7. Uninstalled everything that was related to Visual Studio (Web Essentials, .Net Frameworks, Command Tools etc), check in Ccleaner,
       it will be much faster.
8. Installed Visual Studio with Update 3 and... It was broken right after installation, missing files errors
9. I repaired the installation and everything seemed to work but... localization, language files didn't work, caused visual
   studio to
       show errors or simply hang.
10. I tried to reinstall language pack but I received error "this language is already installed". I couldn't uninstall it
    either. I finally added language files manually:

    - in VS folder in Program Files searched for '1033' and 'en' folders
    - opened my acronis partition backup
    - added to every directory where one of the two folders was found, folder equivalents of my language '10xx' or 'xx'
    - **WARNING:** If you won't do it for EVERY folder, you will get assembly missing error, or your visual studio will have spikes (especially in .aspx files). Don't copy paste it all at once either cuz if you place localization files for assemblies, extensions you don't have, it will cause errors too.
    - **TIP:** If you don't have backup, simply take this files from someone else, they should generally work, no matter which update VS of the other person have.

Its unfortunate that no one had better answer for me but I do hope that this will at least help guys in similar situation.

Comment: Have you tried installing VS web tools? http://www.asp.net/downloads

Comment: Here is installation window: http://www.ultraimg.com/images/6NGC8.jpg, and here is what i got installed list: http://www.ultraimg.com/images/qZM1N.jpg, I believe this updates were included in update 2

Comment: 1. What revision of VS are you using? (Express, pro, etc). 2. You do have Internet connection an that PC with VS and you have installed updates to VS, right?