# Can't create new MVC5 project or any other ASP .NET projects in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

When I attempt to create a new MVC5 project, I get a template selection dialog that doesn't load any options. I am unable to select a project type (ex. MVC, Web forms, Web API) and create the project.

It appears like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaVac.png

To produce this issue, I go to **File -> New Project -> Visual C# -> Web -> ASP .NET Web Application**

After clicking OK, the point where I select the ASP .NET project template I want just sits there empty.

I am running Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate Update 3 and have tried the following:

- Safe mode
- Resetting Visual Studio
- Running devenv /installvstemplates
- Running Repair via Setup

**UPDATE**: This has been resolved for me by xinqui's response below. I deleted the following 3 files and am able to create new ASP .NET Web Application projects now!

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Internal.Contracts.dll
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.WindowsAzure.Contracts.dll
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.WindowsAzure.Explorer.dll

Comment: Is there anything inside of C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\WebTemplates?

Comment: @Jimmy I've got the same problem, performed the same steps as altOnTab and inside my folder I see: MVC, WebApi, WebForms, all with vb and c# folders and 1033 folders with contens below

Comment: Issue reported here: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/941866/cannot-create-new-asp-net-project-after-installing-update-3

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'm from Microsoft web platform and tools team.  In all of the problem reports we get, we find that there are several extra assemblies 
that did not get removed from installation process. Even we still don't know which 
installation process sequence caused the issue yet, we've be able to solve the problem 
by the following steps. Please try the workaround and let us know if it doesn't fix your 
problem.  Thank you very much for all the support.

1. Close VS.
   Goto C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies, 
   delete the following assemblies if they exist:
   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.WindowsAzure.Contracts.dll
   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.WindowsAzure.Explorer.dll
   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Internal.Contracts.dll
2. Start VS2013 with update 3, try to create a ASP.NET Web application, see if the template 
   exists and project can be created successfully.

Comment: I did not see the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Internal.Contracts.dll, but removing the two other dll's fixed my installation. Thanks!

Comment: This is also helped with an issue I had where Azure websites would not display anywhere inside of VS2013. Neither from Server Explorer or the publishing dialog.

Comment: FYI, this problem is fixed in the next release of VS2013 update.

Comment: Unfortunately I have none of these files, VS2013.4 Community, but I don't have the web projects either. I do have some in a "2010 version" folder or something like that, but not the same folders/projects that I have in VS2013 pro at work.

Answer (score 0):

Info for XINQIU ...

I seemed to replicate this by trying to create a Web Api project and it asking me to update my account or re-log into my MS account on the right of this dialogue. I ignored this, closed the dialogue and then re-tried to add this project type. I was then presented with an empty dialogue.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Have you tried the latest VS2013 Update 4 and see if it still have the problem?

Answer (score -3):

I uninstalled VS, deleted the whole "Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0" directory, and reinstalled VS Express Web 2013 Update 3.

Others have mentioned deleting [.dlls](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/941866/cannot-create-new-asp-net-project-after-installing-update-3) or using [gacutil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15173618/the-web-publishing-extension-is-not-installed-which-is-required-to-publish/25190969#25190969). I just wanted to start with fresh files. My stuff works now.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).