# Visual Studio 2013: "New ASP.NET Project" doesn't show templates to choose from

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, vs-web-application-project

https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5fN5.jpg

I can't create a new ASP.NET Web Project via template. Clicking on "OK" crashes VS 2013 or shows the error message "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

I'm using MS Windows 8.1 + Visual Studio 2013 Premium Update 3. 
Extensions I am using:

.NET Reflector Pro

Brace Completer

Visual Power Tools

Web Essentials 2013 for Update 3

Maybe someone knows whats going on? I am running VS 2013 as admin. :(
I tried disabling all Extension, doesn't help.

It's a fresh install from MSDN.

Edit:
I just recognized that the templates show up, when I choose a .NET framework below 4.5:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVkTr.jpg

EDIT 2: 
Okay, reinstalling didn't help. I also uninstalled everything .NET related.

Comment: Uninstall, then reinstall, or try a repair installation.

Comment: Hi Tieson, Thanks for your answer, I just recognized that the templates show up, when I choose a .NET framework below 4.5

Reinstalling everything takes up to 1 hour and I guess I am missing something else?! I will first try to reinstall the .NET Framework + MVC 5.

Comment: Okay, reinstalling didn't help. I also uninstalled everything .NET related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the Problem.

in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies are three assemblies that prevent VS 2013 from showing up the assemblies. See this Question/Answer:

[Can't create new MVC5 project or any other ASP .NET projects in Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25270008/cant-create-new-mvc5-project-or-any-other-asp-net-projects-in-visual-studio-20)